# How to scrape off text from each individual page

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to figure out how to scrape off text from an element within a loop that iterates pages. Below is a code that iterates pages but I haven't been able to figure out how to print out a list of text.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
teacher = pd.DataFrame(columns=['test'])

driver.get("https://www.glowacademy.net/staff_directory")
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fa-arrow-right"))).click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        break
driver.quit()

print(teacher)
```

I have been able to use `.text` from an element attribute before, but this has not worked for this specific site. If someone can explain how does `.text` I would greatly appreciate it. I am a novice to this so please bear with me. If there is a more efficient way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: No one is going to be able to help you unless you can provide the actual errors and the webpage with the text that you are trying to scrape.

Comment: `find_elements()` returns a _list_ of elements.  Lists don't have a `.text` attribute.  This code won't even run.  If you're getting an exception, please say so.

Comment: second = names.text -> second= [x.text for x in names] should make a list of names.